# Why is this bitcount code not passing its tests?

Tags: c, bit

I'm now working on the bit.c lab. I made the function bitCount. I think it's perfect, but it cannot pass the test. I don't know why.

```
int bitCount(int x) {
    unsigned int a = 0x01010101;
    int b;
    int result = 0;
    result += a&x;
    result += a&(x>>1);
    result += a&(x>>2);
    result += a&(x>>3);
    result += a&(x>>4);
    result += a&(x>>5);
    result += a&(x>>6);
    result += a&(x>>7);
    b = result + result >> 8;
    b = b + result >> 16;
    b = b + result >> 24;
    return b&0xff;
}
```

Comment: Give an example of a test that does not pass.

Comment: "perfect" would mean that no improvement is possible. If it fails a test, there is plenty of room for improvement.

Comment: Are you targeting a known `sizeof (int)`, or are you just guessing it's 32 bits wide?

Answer (score 3):

You are summing the wrong bits, because `+` has higher precedence than `>>`, in these rows:

```
b = result + result >> 8;
b = b + result >> 16;
b = b + result >> 24;
```

Let's assume that `result == 0x01020304`:

- The expression `result + result >> 8` will result in `0x01020304 + 0x01020304 >> 8`, and then `0x02040608 >> 8`, and finally `0x020406`.
- The expression `b = b + result >> 16` will result in `0x020406 + 0x01020304 >> 16`, and then `0x0104070A >> 16`, and finally `0x010407`.
- The expression `b = b + result >> 24` will result in `0x010407 + 0x01020304 >> 24`, and then `0x0103070B >> 24`, and finally `0x010307`.
- At the end expression `b&0xff` results in `0x07`. Not the result `0x0A` or 10 we were expecting.

Thus you must:

1. Make sure shift is done before addition. Use parenthesis `()`.
2. Mask unnecessary bits out with `& 0xFF`. Note that this is not strictly necessary since there is the `b&0xff`, but in my opinion it makes the intent clearer.

Example:

```
b = (result & 0xFF) + (result >> 8 & 0xFF);
b = b + (result >> 16 & 0xFF);
b = b + (result >> 24 & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Good catch on the precedence but I'm not convinced the early masking is necessary.

Comment: @Rup Yes, I started doubting that myself too. Edited.

Comment: Problems with precedence could be eliminated completely: `b = result; b += result>>16; b += b>>8; return b&0xFF;` (Here bits mustn't be masked out before the final result)